# Where in the linux kernel does "mmap" looks at the file inode to see if it's already loaded?

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

I want to `kprobe` the function that maps new files onto the memory, but i'm having difficulty finding the function that checks if the file descriptor is already loaded.

I tried hooking the `mmap` syscall but that's not really helping because I get already mapped files like `libc.so`.

I can't seem to figure out if it's filesystem related or memory related, I looked in both places and can't find where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The inode is a kernel-private object.  The kernel does not use libc.so.   User level programs (which may use libc.so) cannot directly reference inodes; instead they have a process local identifier (a file descriptor) which the kernel knows how to translate to the appropriate structure.

So, you are looking in the wrong place.